# how to get attribute value without namespace?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using xpath to extract the value of an attribute but the attribute has a namespace, how can I get the value of the xpath without the namespace or better yet, is there a way to replace the namespace with another?

xpath looks something like this

```
string(//*:root/*:element/@attribute)
```

this returns `_01_1:SomeValue` I want just `SomeValue` or `ns:SomeValue`.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the actual XML but the below is a xml that can be used for reference.

```
<root xmlns:_01_1="http://SOMEURL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<element xsi:attribute="_01_1:SomeValue">Element Value</element>
</root>
```

Here i want to have just `SomeValue` or maybe replace `_01_1` with something (like `ns`) and get `ns:SomeValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `local-name()`?

`string(root/*:element/@*[local-name()='attribute'])`
This will give you "SomeValue" instead of "_01_1:SomeValue".

Example:

```
<root>
<hello xmlns:foo="http:asdf.com">
<something foo:yo="hi">
</something>
</hello>
</root>

string(root/hello/@*[local-name()='yo'])
```

returns `'hi'`

If you have something like:

```
<root>
    <hello xmlns:foo="http:asdf.com">
    <something foo:yo="01_1:hi">
    </something>
    </hello>
    </root>
```

And want the 01_1: removed, you could wrap the result in translate like so:

```
translate(string(root/hello/@*[local-name()='yo']),"_01_1:","")
```

You could apply the above to your original XPath without the use of `local-name()` if you wish to go this route.

For the supplied XML in the question:

```
translate(string(root/element/@*[local-name()='attribute']), "_01_1:","")
```

`@*` will return all attributes of the node, so in this case all attributes of `element`.
You can replace anything you wish with the translate() operation as I did with a blank space, and it will map the given parameter of "_01_1:" to that value. So if you would prefer a result of "ns:SomeValue" then use:

```
translate(string(root/element/@*[local-name()='attribute']), "_01_1:","ns:")
```

Using `//` in place of just root is an example of a relative path vs an absolute path. If you are unsure of where in the document you are looking for your data or where your target node begins, you can use the `//` and `*` identifiers to check a broader range. Ex) `//root` = "Start at the root element and follow all paths starting from the top and traversing to the bottom" while just `root/element/etc` will say "only check the `etc` nodes following a direct path from `root->element->etc`, and is relative to the literal *root* of the document.

Comment: What will this give me? Can you use a xml to show how this will work? Unfortunately, I cannot share the xml.

Comment: in my case hi is _01_1:hi and i just want hi or maybe replace _01_1 with something else. I'll add an xml to my question.

Comment: so the attribute value itself contains namespace information?

Comment: Ok- Strange, but added additional step for that.

Comment: what does //@* do? and if i replace "" with "ns" would I get `ns:hi`? Also, shouldn't the xpath have // before root?

Comment: sure np, will update with an explanation. Also, you don't need to use // there with @*, was a typo.

Comment: You should beware of using translate like this because translate replaces charachter by charachter so for example `translate('_01_1:something','_01_1:','ns:')` should actually return `ns:n:something` instead of `ns:something`. 
A better way would be to use something like `concat('ns:',substring-after(@*[local-name()='yo'],':'))`

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz That's not how it works actually, but substring-after isn't a bad alternative. A downvote isn't necessary either.

Comment: @JWiley I downvoted because the last example of your use of translate produces an incorrect result. If you translate `_01_1:` with `ns:` every `_` will be replaced by `n` every `0` by `s` and every `1` by `:`, so the result will be `ns:n:`. That is how translate works. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate

Comment: also your first translate will remove every _ 0 1 and :, so if you you'd have `translate('_01_1:some01','_01_1:','')` you would get `some` and not `some01`

Answer (score 0):

For your example to get just `SomeValue`:

```
substring-after(/root/element/@*[local-name()='attribute'],':')
```

This will return the Substring after the first appearance of `:`

---

To prepend the `ns:` do:

```
concat('ns:',substring-after(/root/element/@*[local-name()='attribute'],':'))
```